# How to do an indirect file download using php and volley android

Tags: php, android, download, android-volley

I'm a beginner when it comes to any form of http and volley connections with android as well as with file download and currently working on a project that requires both for android. I have files saved in a location that I cannot directly access through https to download using volley. I need to use a POST call to php to force a download through volley to my application. I've seen tutorials on how to do a force download using the HTTPCilent information however, my app doesn't support the use of direct HTTPClient calls. We're handling larger sized files. Specifically, my app downloads an sfb file generated for android sceneform.

I've attempted to have it where volley sends a string POST request to my php page which echos back the contents of the file. However, when I attempt to then display the sfb I get an indexing error from sceneform when trying to put my model on the screen. It has already been verified that the original file when stored directly in my application displays properly.

Does anyone know how to do this type of download with volley? And if it's not possible is there another way without using the HTTPClient library to do this?

Below are sections of my code that currently handle communication between my php and application:

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$fileID = $_POST["model_id"];
$filePath = $_POST["model_path"];

$downloadPath = "<dir only this page can get to> /$fileID/$filePath";

readfile($downloadPath);
//$fileStr = file_get_contents ($downloadPath);
// echo $fileStr;
?>
```

Android:

```
    private StringRequest generatePhpDownloadRequest(String FileName, String FileID)
    {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, WebsiteInterface.DOWNLOAD_URL_STRING,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                        //@todo save the return information
                        /*if(response.length() > 60) {
                            createAlertDialog("LNG:" + response.substring(0, 56));
                        }else {
                            createAlertDialog(response);
                        }*/
                        if(response.length() > 10)
                        {
                            try {
                                if (response!=null) {

                                    FileOutputStream outputStream;
                                    String name=ModelInformation[0];
                                    outputStream = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    outputStream.write(response.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                                    outputStream.close();

                                    ReturnWithResult(RESULT_OK, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
                                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Download complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                ReturnWithResult(RESULT_CANCELED, "KEY_ERROR: UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                            }

                            ReturnWithResult(RESULT_OK, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            ReturnWithResult(RESULT_CANCELED, "invalid file");

                        }
                        //ReturnWithResult(RESULT_CANCELED, "Sucess but no file save");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        String msg = "unknown error";
                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            //This indicates that the reuest has either time out or there is no connection
                            //Log.d(TAG, "Connection Error!");
                            msg = "Connection Error!";
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            //Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
                            //Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error!");
                            msg = "Authentication Error!";
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
                            //Log.d(TAG, "Server Error!");
                            msg = "Server Error!";
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
                            //Log.d(TAG, "Network Error!");
                            msg = "Network Error!";
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
                            //Log.d(TAG, "Parsing Error!");
                            msg = "Parsing Error!";
                        }
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        ReturnWithResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, "VOLLEY: " + msg);
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("model_id", FileID);
                params.put("model_path", FileName);

                return params;
            }
        };
        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to do it using Volley. I was able to use the InputStreamVollyRequest obtained from [here](https://mobikul.com/downloading-files-using-volley/). By adding my variables to the parameters and calling my php file I am able to successfully download the files indirectly from my database. Below are the snippets of my code that now sucessfully executes. (the specifics regarding my file paths and parameters have been abstracted out). Note it appears the parameters don't do anything but I abstracted out how I use them to determine the relative file path. I also as of this post don't have error handling it will simply save the error message into the file generated on the application with the file name being the value of param1.

Android: java

```
private InputStreamVolleyRequest generatePHPDownloadRequest(String param1Value, String param2Value)
{

Map<String,String> inParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
inParams.put("param1", param1Value);
inParams.put("param2", param2Value);

 String requestURL = WebsiteInterface.DOWNLOAD_URL_STRING;
InputStreamVolleyRequest request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestURL,
        new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
                // TODO handle the response
                try {
                    if (response!=null) {

                        FileOutputStream outputStream;
                        String name=param1Value;
                        outputStream = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        outputStream.write(response);
                        outputStream.close();

                        ReturnWithResult(RESULT_OK, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Download complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ReturnWithResult(RESULT_CANCELED, "KEY_ERROR: UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                }
            }
        } ,new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO handle the error
            error.printStackTrace();
            String msg = "unknown error";
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            //This indicates that the reuest has either time out or there is no connection
            //Log.d(TAG, "Connection Error!");
                msg = "Connection Error!";
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            //Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
            //Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error!");
                msg = "Authentication Error!";
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
            //Log.d(TAG, "Server Error!");
                msg = "Server Error!";
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
            //Log.d(TAG, "Network Error!");
                msg = "Network Error!";
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
            //Log.d(TAG, "Parsing Error!");
                msg = "Parsing Error!";
            }
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        ReturnWithResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, "VOLLEY: " + msg);
    }
}, (HashMap<String, String>) inParams);

return request;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if(!isset($_POST["param1"]))
{
    exit("PARAM 1 EMPTY");        
}

if(!isset($_POST["param2"]))
{
    exit("PARAM 2 EMPTY");
}

$param1Value = $_POST["param1"];
$param2Value = $_POST["param2"];

$downloadPath = "<relative path from php file location to the desired file>";

readfile($downloadPath);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use HttpConnection call to download File Payload,
Here is the code,

```
private static final String twoHyphens = "--";
private static final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private static final String boundary = "*****";

private String uploadFile(File sourceFile) {
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL_POST_MESSAGE_FILE).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        String boundary = "---------------------------boundary";
        String tail = lineEnd + "--" + boundary + "--" + lineEnd;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        connection.setRequestProperty(modelHeader.getValue(), modelHeader.getValue());
        String metadataPart = "--" + boundary + lineEnd
                + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n\r\n"
                + "" + lineEnd;
        long fileLength = sourceFile.length() + tail.length();
        String stringData = metadataPart + "--" + boundary + lineEnd
                + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\""
                + sourceFile.getName() + "\"\r\n"
                + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + lineEnd
                + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd + "Content-length: " + fileLength + lineEnd + lineEnd;
        long requestLength = stringData.length() + fileLength;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + requestLength);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) requestLength);
        connection.connect();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(stringData);
        out.flush();
        int bytesRead;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        BufferedInputStream bufInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        byte buf[] = new byte[(int) sourceFile.length() / 200];
        while ((bytesRead = bufInput.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.writeBytes(tail);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(VolleyDownUpFiles.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage() + " ");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        String str;
        if ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            inStream.close();
            return str;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Tag", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or for More Better ways,
There is an Library which i personally recommend to any android developer who love Light weight Volley for Api Integrations.

```
https://github.com/Lib-Jamun/Volley

dependencies {
    compile 'tk.jamun:volley:0.0.4'
}
```

His documentation is available for 0.0.4 version for now,
But Beauty of this library is on 0.0.7 version where you don't need to parse or creaete JSON manually you can just need to pass your model class and other things done automatically.
Its File Related classes for BackGround and Normal Use, Its getting response of your Api methods are very strong and many more things you get there.

Comment: My webpage is on an HTTPS webpage will the HTTP connection code you provided still work?